# Roblox Studio 1v1 arena spawning

Tags: roblox

I'm making a 1v1 arena game, but I'm having some issues with spawning players in arenas. I want it so when they click on a button on the menu called "Play Random", it will wait until another player clicks it too, and if so, teleports them both to one arena; one player on 1 spawn point and the second player on the second spawn point. When they finish, they should both be teleported to the menu again so others can play at this arena (I've made 3 arenas).

```lua
function Click(mouse)
game.Players.LocalPlayer.TeamColor = BrickColor.new("Black")
wait(5)
for i, v in pairs(game.Teams["Waiting"]:GetPlayers())do
    local randomPlayer = game.Teams["Waiting"]:GetPlayers()
    [math.random(1,#game.Teams["Waiting"]:GetPlayers())]
    randomPlayer.TeamColor = BrickColor.new("Lime green") or BrickColor.new("Toothpaste")
end
end


script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:connect(Click)
```

This is the script for the Play Random button:

[Teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hOtl.png)

[Main Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htfb7.png)

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: I don't know how to do a system that would pick 2 random players from the team "waiting" (when they press play random then they go to the team waiting) and then those 2 players will teleport to 1 arena (i made 3 arenas each one with 2 spawn points) then 1 player spawns on one side adn other one at the other side, other ppl that want to play and press play button are teleported to the other free arenas if every arena is occupied then they just wait for one to be free when tehers 2 ppl fighting then when one of the gets killed they are teleported back to the lobby.

Answer (score 0):

first, put the script into starterpack folder, then open the script (the 1v1 script) and click on your keyboard ALT F4 at the same time, then it will force the script to start at that very moment and should work. Good Luck!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).